# Getting only last element of arraylist and losing old elements

Tags: java

I have a problem about Arraylists. I created an arraylist of user defined object. In my drawing program, I created a class which takes only this arraylist. In another class I create this object, and I create another arraylist which takes these objects. You can understand better if you can look up my code. The problem is I have to remove all elements of the object's arraylist after adding to the last arraylist. But I always lose elements after removing. I used clone() method then I keep always last elements. I know its coplicated here, sorry about my english, you can understand clearly what I mean if you can check my code.

```
 public class Lines {

public int id;
public Point point1;
public Point point2;
public int[] denklem;
}

public class Devline {
ArrayList<Lines> segmentim = new ArrayList<Lines>();

 }
...
Devline devarray = new Devline();
Devline devarray3 = new Devline();
ArrayList<Devline> devarray2 = new ArrayList<Devline>();

if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e) == true){
        devarray3.segmentim =  (ArrayList<Lines>) devarray.segmentim.clone();
        devarray2.add(devarray3);
        devarray = new Devline();
        begin = true;

    }
```

Here how I add an element to devarray.

```
  devarray.segmentim.add(l1);
```

I need to add all elements to my devarray2 list. Each time I click rightbutton it will add devarray elements into devarray2, so I can make many different devarray elements inside devarray2. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
devarray3.segmentim =  (ArrayList<Lines>) devarray.segmentim.clone();
devarray2.add(devarray3);
```

You are repeatedly adding the same `Devline` object to the `ArrayList`. Its `segmentim` is getting changed bu it is affecting all elements in the ArrayList.

You need to add a **new** `Devline` to the `devaray2 ArrayList` in each iteration. Since you are creating new `devarray` you can use that one itself:

```
devarray2.add(devarray);
devarray = new Devline();
begin = true;
```

Also you should change the names -- `devarray` is not an array, it should be `devLine` and the class `Lines` should be called `Line`

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

```
devarray3.segmentim =   new ArrayList<Lines>(devarray.segmentim);
```

to copy the devarray2 arraylist ?